# Write to file using spring

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm trying to write the name of a new 'item' into a text file, but I get some kind of error when doing this, it's like it reads from and writes to different files, this is what I've got.

CsvItemDao.java

```
public class CsvItemDao implements ItemDao {

private Resource csvResource;

public void setCsvResource(Resource csvResource){
    this.csvResource = csvResource;
}

    public List<Item> newItem() throws Exception {

    List<Item> results = new ArrayList<Item>();
    String name;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvResource.getFile()));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] fields = line.split(",");
        String itemName = fields[0];
        Item item = new Item(itemName);
        results.add(item);
    }
    br.close();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter new item");
    name = input.nextLine();

    Item item = new Item(name);

    results.add(item);

    try {

        //BufferedWriter fw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(csvResource.getFile()));

        File file = new File (String.valueOf(csvResource.getFile()));
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            bw.write(results.get(i).getItemName() + "\n");
        }
        bw.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return results;
}
```

}

and in my spring-config.xml I have this

```
    <bean id="itemDao"
      class="foo.bar.CsvItemDao">
    <property name="csvResource" value="items.csv"/>
</bean>
<bean id="ItemService"
      class="foo.bar.ItemService">
    <property name="itemDao" ref="itemDao"/>
</bean>
```

The funny thing is, this works, it's just that my 'items.csv' file in resources doesn't get updated, but when I read from the file I get my recently writed items, I hope you understand, and tell me if I can give additional information.

EDIT: 
There is no error message, it works, it's just that if I open the file (items.csv) I will only see the initial list, not the items I have added, but if I read from the list into the program I see all items, why can't I see the added items in the list? I belive it has something to do with the filewriter, maybe that it doesn't close or something.

Comment: Posting the error messages would help.

Comment: please add the stacktrace